# R: Data visualization using Plot to plot APcluster result with more than 15 features

Tags: r, data-visualization, cluster-analysis

I'm dealing with a dataframe of 43 columns(features measured) and a number of rows.

I  performed the clustering analysis using affinity propagation in R, using the apcluster package.

Things went well after normalized the data to calculate the similarity matrix. And I got 17 clusters.

Now that I want to plot them using plot(ap_result, data) then I got a warning saying

```
 Error in .local(x, y, ...) : cannot plot more than 15 features at once
```

Anyway I can fix this and plot my results? The heatmap function does work fine....

Cheers!

Comment: could you add an minimal data example with dput?

Comment: Which version of `apcluster` do you use?
An older version propably limited the features to `n=15` (https://github.com/cran/apcluster/blob/master/R/plot-methods.R)

Comment: @ava Hi ava, I actually figured out how to over come this limit, it's a default setting plot(apres, cytokinefeatures, limitNo = 50) or any number bigger than 15 will do. Although I have to admit 15X15 plots are a little too much for my eye ball. haha

Answer (score 0):

The upper limit of features

A scatter plot matrix with too many features does not make sense because the individual plots will become extremely small. That is why we limited this to 15 features in our package. However, you can always plot pairs of features, one pair after the other. Here is a minimal working example (suppose that `x` is a matrix with d features/columns and l samples/rows):

```
library(apcluster)

d <- ncol(x)
apres <- apcluster(s=negDistMat(p=2), x=x, q=0)

for (i in 1:(d - 1))
    for (j in (i+1):d)
        plot(apres, x[, c(i, j)])
```